# JS specify HTML elements with its attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to refer to the elements by specifying its multiple attribute

i can do it with only one attribute but i failed to research anything regarding to multiple attribute. Not sure where I should start from

```
var l_id = $(this).get(0).getAttribute('data-href');
$('a[data-href="'+l_id+'"]').css('color', '#C99A0C');
```

The above works as fine but my tag a also has another attribute called data-type, i was doing something like below but failed

```
var l_id = $(this).get(0).getAttribute('data-href');
var l_type = $(this).get(0).getAttribute('data-type');
$('a[data-href="'+l_id+'" data-type="'+l_type+'"]').css('color', '#C99A0C');
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use multiple attributes for one element, this will select all `<a>`'s with **both** your `data-href` AND your `data-type`.

```
$('a[data-href="'+l_id+'"][data-type="'+l_type+'"]').css('color', '#C99A0C');
```

If you are trying to get elements that match either one or the other instead, this will match elements that have the `data-href` as well as elements with the `data-type`.

```
$('a[data-href="'+l_id+'"],a[data-type="'+l_type+'"]').css('color', '#C99A0C');
```

Comment: Thanks Thanks for your quick response. The bottom works just fine coz seemings but the top is not working.

Comment: Oh it works as perfect as your kindness! thanks! Also another question if you bother to help. What is this $(' ') way to refer to html element called? Coz I cant search anything about it or I just dont know the way

Comment: Coz I would also want to refer to such element parent at the same time...

Comment: It is jQuery (most likely nowadays).  To get the parent, you can use `.parent()`.  Example, `$('#creative').parent()` will return the parent element for the element with the ID `creative`.

Comment: Yes! I just searched jQuery and got another answer using `$('#element:parent')`, do they work the same way?

Comment: Yes, that would do the same thing.  :)